# "... should be separated by ... from" or "... from ... by" instead?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

The following is from PEP 8, the official style guide for the Python programming language:

> An inline comment is a comment on the same line as a statement. Inline comments should be separated by at least two spaces from the statement.

Isn't it that it sounds wrong and we should swap "by" and "from" parts?

> Inline comments should be separated from the statement by at least two spaces.

Comment: No, it sounds fine the way it is.  It's just a stylistic choice.

Comment: While the two variations are grammatically (& Idiomatically) correct, the second one is a little more logical. Consider this variation : "[[what]] The statement & the Inline comments should be separated [[how]] by at least two spaces." In the first one, the [[what]] is mixed up with the [[how]] , while in the second one (& in my variation) the [[what]] is complete before the [[how]] is given. Like @stangdon says, this is a Stylistic Choice , given the flexibility in English , which user Rounin has listed. [[ +1 to both Question & Answer ]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, the words

> by at least two spaces

represent an **explicit qualifier** describing *how* the inline comments should be separated from the statement.

Written English is flexible with regard to where we include this qualifier:

- Inline comments should be separated from the statement, by at least two spaces.
- Inline comments should be separated (by at least two spaces) from the statement.
- Inline comments should be separated - *by at least two spaces* - from the statement.
- Inline comments should be separated from the statement - by at least two spaces .
- Inline comments should be separated by at least two spaces from the statement.